# Invalid expression term 'int'

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a patch for my program in C#. 
This is my code :

```
 PAWNit.Licensing.TrialMaker.EditTrial(int 2147483647 , int 2147483647);
```

C# compiler gives me 2 same errors , Invalid expression term 'int'.
Please help me :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to call a function with 2 `int` arguments.  If so remove the `int` specifier and just pass the values

```
PAWNit.Licensing.TrialMaker.EditTrial(2147483647 , 2147483647);
```

Answer (score 1):

When calling a method the type should not be included in the call.

remove "int" so it looks like this:

```
PAWNit.Licensing.TrialMaker.EditTrial(2147483647 , 2147483647);
```

Comment: now it gives me this one error :(  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'PAWNit.Licensing.TrialMaker.EditTrial(int, int)'

Comment: It's a DLL actually , I don't have the code but here it is : https://hostr.co/P6ZKFYm6j0C5

Answer (score 1):

do not include the datatype when passing parameters.

```
PAWNit.Licensing.TrialMaker.EditTrial(2147483647 , 2147483647);
```

and your method looks like this

```
public int EditTrial(int num1 , int num2)
{

}
```